# How to get a particular value in an object in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object

This is my Object:

```
{
    "title": "Student Details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "courses": [
        {
            "courseCode": "101",
            "course": "Physics"
        },
        {
            "courseCode": "102",
            "course": "Chemistry"
        },
        {
            "course": "Math",
            "courseCode": "103"
        }
    ],
    "studentId": "xyz202267"
}
```

I want to get the courseCode  when the course name is the input. If I send 'Math', then 103 needs to be returned.

I was able to get all the courseCodes:

```
let ans = temp.courses.map(obj => obj.courseCode)
```

How do I get just the code when course is input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code can be used  to solve your problem:

You can use the `find` method instead of `map` to find the object needed.
Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp

After that, you can check if the object has been found using the ternary operator `?`. If found, it will provide the **courseCode** otherwise, it will provide **Course not found** string. (You can change it to anything that you see fit to display)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
const temp = {
    "title": "Student Details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "courses": [
        {
            "courseCode": "101",
            "course": "Physics"
        },
        {
            "courseCode": "102",
            "course": "Chemistry"
        },
        {
            "course": "Math",
            "courseCode": "103"
        }
    ],
    "studentId": "xyz202267"
};

let ans = temp.courses.find(obj => obj.course === 'Math' );
ans = ans && ans.courseCode ? ans.courseCode : "Course not found";
console.log(ans);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` instead of `map`

```
let ans = temp.courses.find(obj => obj.course === 'Math' )

console.log(ans?.courseCode)
```